# JNA - Access Method in DLL

Tags: jna

Im new to JNA. Im trying to access a method inside a DLL. I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetACSStatus': The specified procedure could not be found.
    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:179)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:347)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:327)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.GetACSStatus(Unknown Source)
    at TestJNA.main(TestJNA.java:17)
```

Here is the code:

```
public class TestJNA {
    public interface simpleDLLTest extends Library {
        simpleDLLTest INSTANCE = (simpleDLLTest) Native.loadLibrary("IMV1", simpleDLLTest.class);
        public NativeLong GetACSStatus(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        simpleDLLTest sdll = simpleDLLTest.INSTANCE;

        NativeLong result1 = sdll.GetACSStatus();  // calling function
        System.out.println("GetACSStatus(): " + result1);
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What does [depends.exe](http://depenencywalker.com) say your function name is?

Comment: In Dependency Walker the function name is given as '?GetACSStatus@IMV_CameraInterface@@QAEKXZ'

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your code with `extern "C"` so that the symbols are exported without C++ name mangling.

Alternatively you can use the name from the symbol table as the function lookup name (you would need to use a `FunctionMapper`to get the special symbols).

Comment: Thank you. We were able to call the method using the Wrapper.